# dynamic fields in the rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show fields from the database dynamically.i.e, if suppose
in one case my @user object reads from users table
         @user = User.new

in another case @user object reads from posts table
         @user = Post.new

Then dynamically my view(new page) shows the fields based on the model selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% for column in @object.class.column_names %>
  <%= @object.send(column) %>
<% end %>
```

EDITED (To exclude some columns from the view)

```
exclude_columns = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
<% for column in @object.class.column_names 
     next if exclude_columns.include?(column) %>
  <%= @object.send(column) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great thanks but I want to show only some columns from tables,I don't need to show created_at and updated_at. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: OR change `@object.class.column_names` to `@object.class.column_names - exclude_columns` in my first answer

Comment: Thank you so much.It fulfilled my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you are asking for, but perhaps you want to have a look at the presenter pattern. This will let your view make use of one single interface while hiding away  the view logic.

I think this post will give you a nice introduction to the topic: http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/31-exhibit-vs-presenter

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with Salil. you should never do assigns in the view (ERB). If you're doing that, you need to move towards a helper or a presenter depending.

Why would you not just walk the tree? @users should, by name, return a collection of users. @user.posts would walk the relationship tree. I'm curious why you're fighting the rails default way of working. Can you share more code to help us understand?